# AWS Appmesh integration with the services which are present outside the eks

Tags: devops, aws-xray, aws-app-mesh

I need to find out a way to integrate the services that are present in ec2. I have an application of microservice architecture. I deployed the microservices in aws eks. But there are some war files that needs to be deployed in camunda tomcat. And kafka cluster setup in ec2. I can able to see the flow in aws x-ray for the microservives present in eks. How to get the flow of services that are present in ec2. Pls tell a solution for this.

On internet i found a solution using aws cloudmap. But I don’t know how to setup cloudmap for my services present in ec2. There are only few resources for cloudmap on internet.Pls help me out on this issue

Answer (score 0):

To get more detail e2e trace for you application, user has to onboard xray by following dev guide:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-concepts.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-daemon.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-instrumenting-your-app.html